# Simple insert stored procedure not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to make a simple stored procedure but it's not working. When I execute the procedure with my parameters in it, below is the following:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_NewProduct] 
@ProductName nvarchar(50), 
@ProductNumber nvarchar(25), 
@MakeFlag bit, 
@FinishedGoodsFlag bit, 
@Color nvarchar(15), 
@SafetyStockLevel smallint, 
@ReorderPoint smallint, 
@StandardCost money, 
@ListPrice money, 
@DaysToManufacture int, 
@SellStartDate date, 
@rowguid uniqueidentifier, 
@ModifiedDate datetime 

as 

insert dbo.product 
(Name,
ProductNumber,
MakeFlag,
FinishedGoodsFlag,
Color,
SafetyStockLevel,
ReorderPoint,
StandardCost,
ListPrice,
DaysToManufacture,
SellStartDate,
rowguid,
ModifiedDate) 

values 

(@ProductName,
@ProductNumber,
@MakeFlag,
@FinishedGoodsFlag,
@Color, @SafetyStockLevel,
@ReorderPoint,
@StandardCost,
@ListPrice,
@DaysToManufacture,
@SellStartDate,
@rowguid,
@ModifiedDate)
```

Here's the execute query with values of each column:

```
exec sp_NewProduct 'AR-5516','105',0,1,'Red',5,5,0.00,0.00,5,'2018-05-01',newid(),getdate()
```

Comment: Can you add some context and/or the error you are receiving?

Comment: Have you tried adding begin and end on your query?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Simply saying that something is *not working* is not helpful: you need to explain specifically what the problem is - see [ask]. If this question is for [tag:sql-server], you may want to [edit] your question to add that tag. In this case, I'd suggest reading [Aaron Bertrand's best practices for stored procedures](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist), particularly the point about Begin/End.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are dealing with wrong procedure syntax! use following snippets:

```
Create or Alter proc [dbo].[sp_NewProduct] (@ProductName nvarchar(50), @ProductNumber nvarchar(25), @MakeFlag bit, @FinishedGoodsFlag bit, @Color nvarchar(15), @SafetyStockLevel smallint, @ReorderPoint smallint, @StandardCost money, @ListPrice money, @DaysToManufacture int, @SellStartDate date, @rowguid uniqueidentifier, @ModifiedDate datetime)
    As 
    Begin
            Insert dbo.product (Name,ProductNumber,MakeFlag,FinishedGoodsFlag,Color,SafetyStockLevel,ReorderPoint,StandardCost,ListPrice, DaysToManufacture,SellStartDate,rowguid,ModifiedDate) values (@ProductName,@ProductNumber,@MakeFlag,@FinishedGoodsFlag,@Color, @SafetyStockLevel,@ReorderPoint,@StandardCost,@ListPrice,@DaysToManufacture,@SellStartDate,@rowguid,@ModifiedDate)
    End
    Go

 Exec sp_NewProduct 'AR-5516','105',0,1,'Red',5,5,0.00,0.00,5,'2018-05-01',@Id,@DateTime;
```

If you still getting error, store newid()'s value and GetDate()'s value in temporary variable, and call through this variable!

```
  Declare @Id AS UniqueIdentifier = NewId()
  Declare @DateTime as DateTime = GetDate()
  Exec sp_NewProduct 'AR-5516','105',0,1,'Red',5,5,0.00,0.00,5,'2018-05-01',@Id,@DateTime;
```